# Python database widgets/environment like MSAccess

Tags: python, database, widget, rad

First of all, I am sorry if this question doesn't belong to SO since I don't know where else to post it, anyway...

I am looking for a decent python based database development RAD framework with nice data aware widgets and grids. A desktop framework would be much preferable to a web framework (I've developed heavy DB-centric apps in django but the web dev experience is still painful compared to a desktop one), although a web framework will do as long as there are powerful data-centric widgets to go along with it.

Ideally, it should be as useful as say Delphi or MSAccess / VBA (I used to develop using those a long time ago). For the record, I have very good development experience in django and wxPython and as I've said developing heavy data-centric web apps is tough and wxPython although very powerful lacks DB-related widgets.

Please note that the use of Python is mandatory because I've been using this language exclusively for all my projects in the last few years and I can't bear the idea of switching back to more mundane languages.

Thanks for any suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interrested in [Boa](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boa-constructor/) which is Delphi-like, [Dabo](http://dabodev.com/) which is more DB oriented, or [Kexi](http://kexi-project.org/) which is more like Access, there's also [GNUe](http://www.gnuenterprise.org/).

Comment: An interesting set of options, I think it will be either Dabo or GNUe.

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for something similar to Kexi. Unfortunately python scripting is not supported in Kexi for windows. I would like to find something better than MS Access, and it does not have to be based on python. So far I have looked at quite a few IDE's but have not found anything where a GUI and database application can be built us as quickly as in access.
 I think of all the best one I have seen is Alpha 5. There could be something based on Net Beans but I really do not know. Oracle APEX is another one I have heard about but it doesn't support desktop applications (as far as I know).